# mailing lists seems to be dead

Tags: matplotlib

Hi I know there been some changes in matplotlib moving from sourceforge to github.

One thing is not clear, what happen with the maling lists?

matplotlib-users in sourceforge shows activity until july
https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=matplotlib-users
but checking nabble we can see more recent activity.
http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/

It is a little bit confusing, the documentation direct us back to sourceforge.... or should we use stackoverflow for every user related question, comment etc.. I guess the issues on github are reseved for the development process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for raising this. The mailing list isn't dead, although the archiving link you gave certainly looks to be! There was a similar question on the mpl-user's mailinglist [a couple of weeks ago](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/mailing-list-archive-broken-td39227.html) which I will follow up on.

Cheers,

Comment: The mailing list archive still seems dead. See http://sourceforge.net/p/matplotlib/mailman/matplotlib-users/